# stdlib-like library on bare metal environment? (memory management and hopefully pthread support)

Tags: c, pthreads, malloc, std

Is there any stdlib-like library for bare-metal programming? 
I am trying to build a program (supposed to be built on linux) for bare-metal environment. The program is dependent on stdlib and posix lib (malloc, calloc, realloc, free, and pthread usage). I will modify it for single thread anyway.
I was reading https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/tutorials/au-memorymanager/ and maybe I will implement my own memory management. But in my case the program has malloc/realloc/free s of various sizes. If there is any program (open source) supporting memory management (and hopefully pthread too.) please give me an advice. The language is C.

Comment: Implementation of `malloc` typically somehow depends on what your device is and provides, so "bare metal" isn't specific enough. You can [look here](https://github.com/zirias/clang-libdos) for ideas, this is what I did on DOS.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a close look at it sometime later.

Comment: FreeRTOS? ......

Answer (score 0):

For the memory allocation functions, you should be able to adapt [Doug Lea's public domain dlmalloc implementation](ftp://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c).  Read the file for details, but you will need to supply a function for `MORECORE` that requests a chunk of memory - if you're on bare metal then this will probably just return consecutive blocks starting above the location your code is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it sometime later.(I need to find out what to define for comipile. I'm using sparc-xx-elf-gcc.)